# How to debug maven surefire tests in Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, debugging, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to debug my Maven Surefire test suite in eclipse.  I am using TestNg for the test runner. I can run this command from terminal then kick off a "Remote Java Application" in Eclipse to debug:

`mvn clean test -Dmaven.surefire.debug -Dclass=com.myTests.SampleTestClass`

Is it possible to set up a Debug Configuration in Eclipse to so I can just Debug directly from Eclipse without having to run the command in terminal?

This is my maven surefire setup in Pom.xml

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.17</version>
  <configuration>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
      <my_property>${my_property}</my_property>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>listener</name>
        <value>com.myPackage.TestListener</value>
      </property>       
    </properties>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Click on the class -> Run as -> JUnit Test or in your case Click on the class -> Run as -> TestNG Test ? Or in case want to debug it. Debus As instead of "Run As"...

Comment: Maven is part of my project for a few reasons, I don't want to skip that part

Comment: I know but you want to debug the test and not maven-surefire-plugin or maven itself ?

Comment: If you have some parts which are not working if you start them as tests from within Eclipse you are doing things wrong. Can you give information what you are doing?

Comment: If I run from eclipse the "listener" property is ignored

Comment: Of course so you have to give in your arguments for running the test in Eclipse. That can be done.... **But** the real question is: Why do you need such listener ? Apart from that listners can be defined by annotations. So i don't see the problem here?

Comment: @zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz Please share info if you did solve the prob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise), ditch the maven part and just run the tests from eclipse itself.

The Key-Combination you'll want to use after selecting the package containing your TestNG tests is: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd>

To debug JUnitTests, replace the N by T

As to preserving current functionality: To attach a listener to your testng testsuite, use the [`@Listeners`-Annotation](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Listeners.html), where you can attach multiple classes implementing `ITestNGListener` to listen to your suite.

Be aware that ITestNGListener is just a marker interface and has no further functionality.

For the `systemPropertyVariables` defined: You should be able to attach them in your testng run (and debug) configuration.

Comment: I don't want to ditch the maven part.  Maven is part of my project because it handles some setup that I don't get if I run as a TestNG or JUnit test.

Comment: Please add such information to your question ahead of time. I had no idea you needed some setup... Then again I think you might be wrong to rely on maven for test-setup, but I don't have enough information to suggest possibly better alternatives... eh well

Comment: I should be using the test ng @Listeners annotation.